# Injection of $D_6$ into $S_5.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Would anyone happen to recall how to put $D_6$ into $S_5?$ The cyclic generator has to go (up to conjugacy) to $(1 2 3) (4 5),$ but where does the involution go?

Comment: I think [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710591/120540) has a solution.

Comment: I like your answer to that version @pjs36. Pictures are always nice! Do you think that this should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Thank you, @JyrkiLahtonen ! Looking back, I realized some of the wording was a bit funky. Anyway, I don't feel strongly one way or the other (at least, I'm not overly inclined to close) -- that question was about a *specific* isomorphism, to be fair; this one's a bit more broad, I suppose. I think you know better than me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try $a\mapsto (123)(45)$, $b\mapsto (23)$, then the key relation $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$ is satisfied.

Instead of $(23)$ you can use any other 2-cycle acting on $\{1,2,3\}$.

The key to success here is that $D_6\simeq D_3\times C_2$.

Comment: You are most wise :)