# Geometrical interpretation of the faithful actions of $D_6$ and $D_{10}$ on sets of size $5$ and $7$, respectively.

Tags: geometry, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

The dihedral group of order $2n$, $D_n$, acts faithfully on the set of the $n$ vertices of the regular $n$-gon. For $n=6$ and $n=10$, $D_n$ acts faithfully also on sets of size smaller than $n$, respectively $5$ and $7$.

What is the geometrical interpretation of these two faithful actions? In particular, *what are the $5$ and $7$ "geometrical objects" of the regular hexagon and decagon, respectively, on which $D_6$ and $D_{10}$ act faithfully?*

**Edit**. I think I got the point, driven by the comments: when $n=2m$ with $m$ odd, the two $m$-gon inscribed in the $n$-gon and the $m$ pairs of adjacent sides build up a set of size $m+2$ on which $D_n$ acts faithfully.

Comment: For $n=2m$ with $m$ odd, we have $D_n \cong D_m \times C_2$, and the actions that you are talking about are intransitive actions, with $D_m$ in its natural action on $m$ points, and the $C_2$ acting on the other two points - so the faithful action of $D_n$ is on $m+2$ points with orbits of sizes $m$ and $2$.

Comment: A downvote and a vote to close?!?

Comment: I don't quite get it. Why m needs to be odd then?

Comment: This has been asked for $D_6$ before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710591/fastest-way-to-show-that-d-6-to-s-5-is-an-injective-homomorphism/1710743#1710743) (I think this is close enough to vote to close as a duplicate). You can find the more general construction on an [old blog post](https://grossack.site/2021/08/16/embedding-dihedral-groups-efficiently.html) of mine.

Comment: @agent_cracker103, it needs for the action to be faithful. I've reworded the Edit to make it clearer

Comment: I see, @HallaSurvivor, thanks. Before acknowledging mine as duplicate, I wonder whether mine "pairs of adjacent sides" properly play the role of the $2$-gons (diagonals).